# jQuery [data-anchor] seems to be malfunctioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

It's a simple click and scroll to div using anchors. The first one seems to work fine until you click the others. Once you click the second link it just doesn't scroll, instead it only scrolls down a few pixels. If you start pressing them randomly it just becomes a mess of random scrolling to no where.

Here's a pen I made:

https://codepen.io/sergestra/pen/pMrdzp

```js
jQuery.noConflict();

jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

  $('[data-anchor]').click(function() {

    var target = $($(this).data('anchor'));

    if (target.length) {

      $('.right').animate({
        scrollTop: target.offset().top
      }, 1000);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

li {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 20px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

li:hover {
  color: white;
}

.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.left {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  height: 100%;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.colors {
  font-size: 2rem;
  padding: 20px 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.colors:hover {
  color: white;
}

.right {
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
}

.right div {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  height: 200px;
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
  padding: 20px;
  border: 2px solid white;
  color: white;
  font-size: 2rem;
}

#blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

#green {
  background-color: green;
}

#yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}

#red {
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="left">
    <div>
      <div class="colors" data-anchor="#blue">GO TO BLUE</div>
      <div class="colors" data-anchor="#green">GO TO GREEN</div>
      <div class="colors" data-anchor="#yellow">GO TO YELLOW</div>
      <div class="colors" data-anchor="#red">GO TO RED</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="right">
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div id="blue">blue</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div id="green">green</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div id="yellow">yellow</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div id="red">red</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
    <div>gray</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I have tried rearranging my css and html but it doesn't seem to be helping the issue.
Its supposed to just scroll to what ever div I call to but instead it scrolls randomly.

Comment: It should be target[0].offsetTop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just make the following change. https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MNvGgR

```
$('.right').animate({
   scrollTop: target[0].offsetTop
}, 1000);
```